# redux get input text value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following reactjs component.

```
class Login extends Component {

render() {
    if (this.props.session.Authenticated) {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input
                type="button"
                value="Login"
                onClick={() => this.props.LoginAction("admin", "password")}
             />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The Login component makes use of a prop that is set via redux, named "session.Authenticated". If an user session is not authenticated, I present a couple of `input` fields (one for username and another for password) and a `Login` button. If I press on the `Login` button I want to emit an action with the username and password values, passed as parameters. Now, how do I get the values of the two `input` fields for the parameters ?

IOW, I want to remove the hardcoded "admin, password" in the above code with the values of the two `input` fields. How to achieve this ?

All the examples point to `redux-form` which is a new dependency that I do not want to add. I want to keep my dependencies minimal and so using only react, redux and react-redux in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  class Login extends Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           model = {
              login: "",
              password: ""
           }
        }
     }
  render() {
      if (this.props.session.Authenticated) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.model.value.login} onChange={e => this.updateModel(e.target.value, 'login')}placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" value={this.state.model.password }onChange={e => this.updateModel(e.target.value, 'password')} placeholder="Password" />
            <input
                type="button"
                value="Login"
                onClick={() => this.props.LoginAction(this.state.model.login, this.state.model.password)}
             />
        </div>
    );
}

 updateModel(value, name){
    var model = extend({}, this.state.model);
    model[name] = value;
    this.setState({model});
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using redux and so need to maintain state globally. Isn't it a bad practice in redux to have component-specific state ?

Comment: Your `updateModel` method should trigger action and action should update store value

Comment: React require a lot of boilerplate code, so, try to search some libraries for forms. Absolutely sure, that you will find form component that will do all update magic inside of it `form` component.

Comment: I thought about emitting an action during the onChange event of input. But that is a loooooot of boilerplate for a simple action. There is a react-form library but I was trying to minimize dependencies. Seems like it is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: I start to work on large react-based project one year ago, and try some components, but there was no something, that satisfy all my requirements. In the end I write my own lib for forms, that use React.cloneComponent for all props.children, and it require minimum of boilerplate code. Unfortunately, after clone child, ''ref" property work not as expected. But if you are interested, I can share code.

Comment: This is anyway only for a learning experience. So I will learn myself :( Thanks for the offer.